# Resuming on another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-2.2-froyo

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application. I have the following situation:

A user is working with my app and, when he finishes, he presses home button.

I'm wondering if it is possible to re-start my app from an specific activity. For example, if user was in activity B when he pressed home button, I always when to re-start it in activity A.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
Override the onResume() method in Activity B

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
            Intent b= new Intent(context, A.class); 
             startActivity(b);  
             finish();
                          }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep Activity A as your root and add `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"`or `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` to your manifest. This would force your root activity to be relaunched each time when you press home. Check this link for more info

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear